# Issue with Rails 4.2.1 in routing paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

`1) MessageController should check the status
     Failure/Error: get :status
     RuntimeError:
       In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.
     # /Users/vishal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/url_for.rb:13:in _routes`

This error  I am getting on running my specs. 
The route.rb file is valid and when I run rails server and hit status url it shows the page needed, but while running rspec the Test case fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you requiring `rails_helper` or `spec_helper` at the top of your specs?

Comment: @Makoto - I am requiring rails_helper

Answer (score 1):

As the error says.. to use the application helpers in a spec you need to include them explicitly as ApplicationHelper doesn't include them by default:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

Using Rspec.. add to  rspec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

Comment: where would i find ApplicationHelper module?

Comment: Sorry I'm not clear what testing framework you are using (probably my fault). Added and example for RSpec.